# Is winebottler safe to install?

Tags: macos, applications, security, wine

I've been missing [Notepad++](https://mike.kronenberg.org/winebottler-how-to-install-notepad-on-a-mac/) since changing from Windows to macOS and there's an article that says if I use [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) (that's the only thing I miss), it should run.

> WineBottler packages Windows-based programs like browsers, media-players, games or business appli­ca­tions snugly into Mac app-bundles.

The notepad aspect is inconsequential (in fact I nearly didn't add it in). I'm aware of other editors, I'm expressly asking about WineBottler. I don't want to know about running Parallels, etc.

I simply want to know if WineBottler is malicious or not.

Is this known to be safe?

Comment: Also see [How can I run Windows applications on a MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114486/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-on-a-macbook-pro/114487?s=1|0.0000#114487)

Answer (score 3):

### Run Wine

> Wine is a translation layer for Windows applications. It's a bit like
>   a virtual machine but doesn't require the Windows OS. It sits between
>   the Windows application and OS X and makes the application think it's
>   running on Windows by translating all the Windows calls its making to
>   OS X calls.
>
> There are two choices of know of here. The free [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) and
>   the paid-for [CrossOver Mac from CodeWeavers](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-mac/).
>
> Some commercial software is delivered for OS X this way -- I know The
>   Sims 3 game that my wife likes to play on her MacBook Pro is actually
>   the Windows version of the game running under the Wine emulator.
>
> Pros:
>
> - You don't need to buy a copy of Windows
> - Your OS X-based data can be accessed from your Window programs
>
> Cons:
>
> - Application support under Wine can be hit-and-miss. Some apps work well, some don't. Check at http://appdb.winehq.org/ to see if your
>     applications are on the list of tested, supported applications if
>     you're going to try WineBottler. CodeWeavers keeps their own list.
> - Because the Windows applications think they're running on Windows, and not everything Windows does translates perfectly to OS X, some
>     applications can behave erratically.

Source: [How can I run Windows applications on a MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114486/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-on-a-macbook-pro/114487#114487)

> It basically installs enough windows frameworks i.e. registry, and
>   DLLs needed by Windows applications to run. It doesnt install a full
>   out version of windows. It is more or less sandboxed, as well as when
>   you compile an application, you can further sandbox that application
>   in its "own" windows subsystem, making it modular, like most macOS
>   applications. It is safe and does not alter your HD filesystem.

Source: [Reddit - WINE - is it safe to use?](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/6phnxg/wine_is_it_safe_to_use/)

## Notepad++ 7.x in Wine:

> What works
>
> Installs Launches (slowly) Opening/saving files Searching What does
>   not
>
> Default font is not monospace Some high Unicode codepoints (surrogate
>   pairs?) do not display correctly Really slow to launch Workarounds
>
> What was not tested
>
> Anything but basic functionality Hardware tested
>
> Graphics:
>
> GPU: Intel Driver: open source Additional Comments
>
> It works out-of-the-box, you just need to change the font to a
>   monospace one that you have installed.

Source: [WineHQ - Notepad++](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2983)

Answer (score 2):

> I simply want to know if WineBottler is malicious or not.

**Yes**, I had Wine and WineBottler installed for years without problems. As long as you download it from the [official source](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org) you should be fine.

Comment: **Beware**, using TextEdit to edit code can make your code unusable because TextEdit replaces normal quotes with *"smart"* quotes by default.

Comment: Suggesting TextEdit as code editor is the most ridiculous answer I've ever seen on this site, sorry. You cannot even create other files than RTF files with it, although you can edit text files, but it sucks as hell. Best replacement for Notepad++ is Visual Studio Code, imo. Simply use it with [Notepad++ key mappings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.notepadplusplus-keybindings), if you don't want to re-learn key mappings.

Comment: @modiX I don't disagree. Looking over this post from awhile ago, I must have misread Notepad++ as Notepad. I was describing the macOS equivalent, TextEdit. But it should not be used for code editing. Use JetBrains IDEs or Sublime. Do note however, TextEdit can create plaintext files, allowing for html, js, php, etc. to be written.

Comment: P.S. I didn't include Eclipse in that list on purpose....

Comment: @JBis Obviously you have another editor to prefer for code, it's opinion based. And yes, you can (technically) **edit** code files with TextEdit. That's what I included when I said *text files*.